# image not displaying when taking picture from 3rd party camera apps

Tags: android, camera

I have a simple module of working with the camera. When I use the default camera (in-built camera) it is displaying the thumbnail as required. Anyhow when I use 3rd party camera apps(like candycamera, retrica etc) by using packageManager to take a picture, it doesn't show the thumbnail. it crashes sometimes.
I have tried every code within my limits to check that the thumbnail is being displayed but cannot find any relevant solution
Help is appreciated
Thanks

in onCreate()

private void dispatchPicIntent() {

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE );
    }
}
```

in onActivityResult()

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

```
        pictureFile = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    pictureFile);
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
            filePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Post your code. Post the stack trace. Indicate where things go wrong.

Comment: Every camera app can behave as it wants. You should be prepared for not receiving the data you expect. But your app should never crash as you can make the code robust.

Comment: I just did. I could use open source libs but I want to know the logic behind this

Answer (score 0):

You can use CWAC2 library https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2 to take a picture. Really useful and easy to understand library.

Comment: Okay I will try this solution of yours. Meanwhile if there is any other solution not requiring use of dependencies, the logical explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage library to take a picture.its easy to understand.